# Como se atualizar "<form></form>" sem Refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Meu formulário é uma uma sacola de compras, quando .submit() o form #add-cart-head, ele adiciona o produto sem refresh, mas eu queria ter uma resposta que atualiza-se a sacola que fica no topo da página. O "GET" na sequência até funciona, mas não atualiza o form.

O que fazer, ou como fazer ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#add-to-cart-head').submit(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this),
            dados = $this.serialize();
         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            data: dados,
   complete: function(){
   jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://modernita.ambienteprotegido.com/cart/update_cart",
    data: dados});
   },
   error: function(){
                alert("Deu erro");
            }
    });
 return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você já tem quase tudo, o que falta é:

- saber qual o elemento que precisa atualizar
- saber de onde vem o conteudo que quer inserir nesse elemento

Se por exemplo quiser adicionar novo conteudo auma `div` pode usar `$('#idDaMinhaDiv').html('O carrinho foi atualizado!');`. Se o conteudo que fôr exibir fôr estático então o exemplo em cima é o que precisa. Se o conteudo vier do AJAX então tem de passar nos dados que vêm do servidor essa informação.

Você tem duas chamadas AJAX, pode juntar uma função `complete` como na primeira e aí inserir os dados na div. Algo como:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $this.attr('action'),
    data: dados,
    complete: function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://modernita.ambienteprotegido.com/cart/update_cart",
            data: dados,
            complete: function (mensagem) {
                $('#idDaMinhaDiv').html(mensagem);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Deu erro");
    }
});
```