# Botão atualizar dados de uma consulta sem refresh na página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estou criando uma aplicação em PHP(Codeigniter) e me deparei com a seguinte situação. Tenho uma tabela em minha página que trás todos os resultados de uma consulta no banco de dados. Quero criar um botão de atualizar dados porém não queria que o mesmo desse refresh na página. Gostaria de uma ajuda de como posso fazer isto.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Eu recomando você dar uma pesquisada no `AngularJS`

Comment: Porque não faz um jQuery que traz a consulta pra você? sem refresh? Não precisa nem do botão, apenas especificar quantos segundos...

Comment: A nível de esclarecimento: negativei a resposta, porque já temos muitas perguntas (e respostas) a respeito de fazer alguma coisa sem dar refresh

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43087/como-se-atualizar-form-form-sem-refresh?rq=1

Comment: Traduzindo: Você quer fazer uma requisição através do `AJAX`.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza Jquery para fazer uma requisição AJAX.

Quando você clicar no botão refresh você faz uma requisição no servidor retornando um json com o seu resultado desejado no seu caso acredito que uma lista que popula sua tabela.

Exemplo :

```
$("#btnRefresh").click(function(){
      $.get(aquisuaurlqueretornajson)
         .done(function(response){
            $("#nomedatabela tbody tr").remove();//limpar os dados já populados
                for(var i in response){

                    var linhaTabela = $("<tr><td> " + response.algumatributodoseujson + "  </td>" + "</tr>");
                    $("#nomedatabela").append(linhaTabela);

                    }
    });
```