# Update no banco através de javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, javascript-eventos

Preciso fazer um botão que quando o usuário clicar na linha correspondente ele execute o seguinte código sem refresh:

Código da Linha:

```
mysql_query('UPDATE tbl_publicacao SET status = S WHERE cod_publicacao = $cod_publicacao');"
```

Linha:

```
<?php $cod_publicacao = $back_query['cod_publicacao'];
$arquivo = $back_query['arquivo']; 
 echo"<a href='upload/publicacoes/{$razao_social}/{$tipo}/{$titulo}/{$ano}/{$arquivo}'>
<i class='ace-icon fa fa-eye bigger-110 hidden-480'></i>&nbsp;Visualizar Arquivo</a>";
?>
```

Acredito que deva ser uma função onclick em javascript mas eu não sei como desenvolve-la para mudar em javascript

Comment: Um pouco sobre front-end e back-end http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177050/3635

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript é uma linguagem que trabalha do lado do cliente (navegador). Sendo assim, ele não tem conexão direta com um servidor Mysql.

Além do mais, se tivesse, seria um problema, uma vez que você precisaria especificar uma senha  para conexão com o banco.

E assim, qualquer um que lesse seu arquivo Javascript, poderia ver sua senha. Isso seria um problema, não é mesmo?

Portanto, usasse uma linguagem que atue do lado do servidor, como PHP por exemplo, para conectar com o Mysql e fazer alguma operação no banco de dados.

O que pode ser feito é utilizar uma requisição Ajax, que será enviado para o Servidor, e o Servidor por sua vez executará o Mysql e deletará o arquivo.

Talvez você esteja confundindo um pouco os conceitos. Por isso é importante deixar isso claro.

Como dito anteriormente, você pode usar uma requisição com Ajax para isso.

Veja alguns exemplos:

- [Como se atualizar "<form></form>" sem Refresh?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43087/como-se-atualizar-form-form-sem-refresh)
- [Como criar um site sem recarregar a cada clique num link?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link)
- [Fazer upload de arquivo com AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9704/fazer-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax)